# How to get constructor arguments in a method using typetags/mirrors?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

For Case Class:

```
case class MyClass(param1: String, param2: String)
```

Why does this reflective method:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }

  def getSettings[T](paramObj: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) {
    val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val classType = ru.typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
    val cm = m.reflectClass(classType)
    val constructor = tag.tpe.declaration(ru.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMethod = cm.reflectConstructor(constructor)
    val args = constructor.asMethod.paramss.head map { p => (p.name.decoded, p.typeSignature) }
    println(args)
 }
```

When Invoked like so:

```
scala> getSettings(MyClass)
List()
```

Have that output?? Is the constructor not 2 arguments??
I must be missing something really obvious here. The documentation doesn't cover scenarios quite like this.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getSettings(MyClass)
```

`MyClass` is the companion object of class `MyClass`. It has no constructor parameters.

You should rewrite your code like this:

```
def getSettings[T]()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) {
  ...
}

scala> getSettings[MyClass]
List((param1,String), (param2,String))
```

Comment: Ya that's what I was thinking - that it was the companion - as you see the object is called with a $ if you inspect . - I'll try it out.

Comment: Ah I see so you pass the parameter type into the method and the implicit tag is passed in. I'm really new to the reflection api.

Comment: Or `getSettings(MyClass("a","b"))`

Comment: @JasonG `as you see the object is called with a $`. The type of companion object contains `$` (`MyClass$`).

Comment: @JasonG: you could use syntax sugar called `type class` here: `def getSettings[T: TypeTag]() { val tag = implicitly[TypeTag[T]] ...`