# Scala reflection and generics

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I am facing an issue with Scala reflection and generics. I have an abstract class which has this signature:

```
IPartition [T <: IPartition[T]] (val bounds: Array[BoundsInOneDimension], 
val boxId: BoxId = 0, val partitionId: Int = -1, var adjacentPartitions: List[T] = Nil)
```

and a concrete class with this signature:

```
Box (bounds: Array[BoundsInOneDimension], boxId: BoxId = 0, partitionId: Int = -1, adjacentBoxes: List[Box] = Nil) 
extends IPartition[Box] (bounds, boxId, partitionId, adjacentBoxes)
```

What I wanna do is to instantiate the concrete class within a generic method of an `object`. Thus, I have this method:

```
myMethod[SHAPE <: IPartition[SHAPE]] (...) (implicit m:Manifest[SHAPE]): Iterable[SHAPE]
```

and in this method I need to instantiate the generic class SHAPE extending the abstract class above.

By now, I have tried doing this:

```
 m.getClass.getConstructors.apply(0).newInstance(combinations(i).reverse , Int.box(i+1), Int.box(-1)).asInstanceOf[SHAPE]
```

But I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Then I printed the parameter expected by the constructor which are:

```
class scala.Option
class java.lang.Class
class scala.collection.immutable.List
```

And I can't understand this. I expected 4 parameters, or 1, or something similar. Moreover, I didn't expected a `scala.Option` as first parameter, neither a `java.lang.Class` as second.

I can't understand what to do to correctly instantiating the class I need with the proper parameters. May anyone help me?

*** UPDATE ***

Now, I've tried doing this according to @dk14 response

```
for (i <- 0 until combinations.size) yield classTag.runtimeClass.getConstructors.apply(0).newInstance(combinations(i).reverse , Int.box(i+1), Int.box(-1), Nil:List[SHAPE]).asInstanceOf[SHAPE]
```

and I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`. I cannot understand what I'm missing...

*** UPDATE 2 ***

In this case my problem was stupid. And the problem is that I was passing a `List` instead of an `Array` as first parameter. Fixed this, everything worked to me.

Thanks.
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least it works with `ClassTag` (`Manifest`s are deprecated - didn't even try):

```
import scala.reflect._

scala> def myMethod[SHAPE <: IPartition[SHAPE]: ClassTag] (bs: Object, bi: Object, p: Object, a: Object) = classTag[SHAPE].runtimeClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(bs, bi, p, a)
myMethod: [SHAPE <: IPartition[SHAPE]](bs: Object, bi: Object, p: Object, a: Object)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[SHAPE])Any

scala> myMethod[Box](Array(1,2,3), 1: Integer, 1: Integer, List[Box]())
res27: Any = Box@3305055b
```

I assumed that `BoundsInOneDimension` and `BoxId` are integers, but don't think it changes anything. Scala 2.11.2 here.

Here is `getConstructors()(0).getParameterTypes()`:

```
 Array(class [I, int, int, class scala.collection.immutable.List) //`class [I` means Array of integers
```

You may also use `TypeTag` and Scala Reflection (instead of Java's) which is more typesafe - [How to get constructor arguments in a method using typetags/mirrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177427/how-to-get-constructor-arguments-in-a-method-using-typetags-mirrors). Like that:

```
def creator[T <: IPartition[T] : TypeTag]() = {   
  val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val classType = ru.typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
  val constructor = typeTag[T].tpe.declaration(ru.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val constructorMethod = m.reflectClass(classType).reflectConstructor(constructor)
  constructorMethod.apply(Array.empty[Int],2,3,List.empty[Box]) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Scala 2.10.4.  Your other assumption are quite correct (`BoundsInOneDimension` is a class). Now, the constructor parameters are 4 indeed, as I expected. But I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` and I can't figure out why. See the update in my post to see the code I've written which is giving this exception. Thanks.

Comment: I've added version which doesn't require explicit boxing. I'm not sure that `combination(i)` returns `Array` (in result of scala's `combinations` is `Iterator[List]]`, so `i`th element is a `List` - try `.toArray` on it

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem was that it wasn't an `Array`. This was to the fact that before doing thing with reflection I was using another constructor which takes only two parameters and the first one is a `List`. Before the changes you suggested me, I couldn't find that constructor in the constructors' array, while now it is available at the second position of the array. Thank you!